# Short story about secret spy betrayed at a secret party, boss got stuck in trap while looking for files

Tags: identification-request, short-stories

I think I read it five or six years ago from a collection of novels written by one writer. A man is a spy in a secret illegal organization, one day he took part in a secret party, but he had been betrayed by his colleague and been caught. The boss of the organization went to his house for some secret files but he got into a trap and stuck in a room behind a wall. The door was specially designed and it would be closed if there was no pressure. I don't remember the end of the story but I am sure it's short and is in the end of the collection book. I think it like a easy story because I was only 11 at that time.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I think it's a spy story without too much technology except a door with special design.I remembered the door was made in Germany.And there isn't too much about technology and action.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this is "The Cave of Ali Baba" or "The Adventurous Exploit of the Cave of Ali Baba", by Dorothy L. Sayers. It was a bit longer than an average short story IIRC - maybe a "novelette" or "novella", and was the final story in the collection ["Lord Peter Views the Body"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lord_Peter_Views_the_Body#The_Adventurous_Exploit_of_the_Cave_of_Ali_Baba)

> A man is a spy in a secret illegal organization

Lord Peter Wimsey fakes his death, disguises himself as a disgruntled ex-footman, lives in this role for about a year, and is eventually recruited by a criminal organisation. I don't know if he made contact with them or the other way round. He claimed to have insider information that would help them rob Wimsey's family.

> one day he took part in a secret party,but he had been be betrayed by his colleague and been caught.

He did attend a secret party at which all the organisation's members were present. They were all identified by numbers, not names - a bit like the Prisoner. He was unmasked by Number One - but I don't think he was betrayed, I think it was just that the villain had deduced his true identity.

> The boss of the organization went to his house for some secret files but he got into a trap and stuck in a room behind a wall. The door was specially designed and it would be closed if there was no pressure.

Number One did indeed go to Wimsey's home to retrieve *something* from a secret cupboard. There was a complicated setup with an outer door, an outer-inner door, and an inner door. This sprung a trap and left Number One trapped in the room, possibly running out of oxygen. Wimsey had (seemingly under duress) revealed the existence of the "outer-inner door" so that, on seeing it, Number One would think he'd found the trap, and be too careless to notice the "inner-inner door".

The story was great fun, really funny. In my opinion, it was like a cross between a standard Wimsey short and an episode of 60s Batman!